# What are the most used encryption/decryption keys?

Tags: encryption, key

I started Working On a encryption project, but I am facing a problem with the leak of encryption keys. Is there a list of the most popular encryption keys used, like the password lists of most used passwords?

Comment: How about googling for "most used passwords"? Was the result not good enough?

Comment: password are not encryption keys when Term " Encryption " is used  we are talking about 3 parts   Encryption Key   plain text  cipher text

Comment: You should not really have any that are used more than once. That's a feature of a random choice of number with a huge number of digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keys differ significantly from the passwords. Key can be derived from password (for example via PBKDF2), but it is not some value that is chosen by programmer, it is generated by computer, and (if correctly implemented) partially or wholly random.

I doubt that there are some "often used" keys, since they are basically big random numbers.

Comment: thanks , what i mean from the password list here is the term list of most used  so i thought there  could be list by some used keys in encryption like passwords   , any way thanks :)

Comment: There are some cases where certain values are incorrectly used repeatedly, which cause insecure implementations of secure protocols. For example, the weak Diffie-Hellman parameters that shipped as default with some server implementations. https://weakdh.org/

Comment: Thankfully cryptographers (who work with keys) are more security-minded than users (who work with passwords) ;)

Comment: leaks can always happen   :)